# How to repeat a row multiple times (100) with a certain change

Tags: bash

I have a file having row

```
file1 -int sch1.inp -HOST all.q:1 -NJOBS 1 -TMPLAUNCHDIR
```

I want to repeat this row 100 times with this change (sch2, sch3, sch4 etc)

```
file1 -int sch2.inp -HOST all.q:1 -NJOBS 1 -TMPLAUNCHDIR
file1 -int sch3.inp -HOST all.q:1 -NJOBS 1 -TMPLAUNCHDIR
file1 -int sch4.inp -HOST all.q:1 -NJOBS 1 -TMPLAUNCHDIR
```

how can i do this.

Thank you so much in advance.
Rehan

Comment: What have you tried? You'll need to give an effort first.

Comment: Vaguely related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672996/how-can-i-see-if-a-consecutive-number-name-file-is-missing-some-file/

Comment: Are the `sch*.inp` things files that exist in the current directory? If so, would you want to run the command for each such file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This answer is based on the current question:

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$(cat infile)
echo "$string" > outfile
string=${string/sch1/sch%d}

for ((i=2; i<101; i++))
do
   printf "$string\n" "$i" >> outfile
done

# uncomment to overwrite input file
# mv outfile infile
```

The following answer is based on the OP's original question - not the current question. The OP accepted this answer as correct.

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$(cat infile)
echo "$string" > outfile

for ((i=2; i<101; i++))
do
   echo "${string/sch1/sch"$i"}" >> outfile
done

# uncomment to overwrite input file
# mv outfile infile
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: And just for the sheer hell of it, that `for` statement can be replaced with `for i in $(seq 2 100)`.

Comment: @Bib  True.  However `seq` is not a shell builtin.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf 'file1 -int sch%s.inp -HOST all.q:1 -NJOBS 1 -TMPLAUNCHDIR\n' {1..100}
```

Or:

```
seq -f 'file1 -int sch%g.inp -HOST all.q:1 -NJOBS 1 -TMPLAUNCHDIR' 100
```

Or:

```
jot -w 'file1 -int sch%d.inp -HOST all.q:1 -NJOBS 1 -TMPLAUNCHDIR' 100
```

Would produce the whole output.

If you wanted to start with that:

```
file1 -int sch1.inp -HOST all.q:1 -NJOBS 1 -TMPLAUNCHDIR
```

line in vim, and reproduce it with the second number of the line increased 99 times, you could do `qayypw^Aq98@a` with the cursor positioned on that line.

Where:

- `qa`: starts recording the `a` macro
- `yy`: yanks (copies) the whole line.
- `p`: pastes it underneath
- `w`: moves to the next word (to skip the first which does also contain a number).
- `^A` (Ctrl+A): increments the number under the cursor or if no number under the cursor, the next one found to the right of it.
- `q`: finish recording the macro
- `98@a`: run the `a` macro 98 times.

Or whenever `file1 -int <something><number>.inp` is found at the start of a line, reproduce the line 100 times with the number increased:

```
perl -pe 'if (m{^file1 -int \S*?\K\d+(?=\.inp)}) {
            for my $i ($& .. $& + 99) {
              print;
              s//$i/;
            }
          }' < your-file
```