# Searching for a missing number in a sequence of numbers

Tags: text-processing

So I have a file that has whole bunch of information and each "block" of information has it's own unique identifier, which is shown as:

```
"index": number
```

after using the following command in linux:

```
$ cat file | grep index
```

I get this result:

```
"index": 1
"index": 2
"index": 3
...
"index": 10001
```

In between them is a whole range of numbers in sequential format.

Somewhere in there, there is a missing number and I am trying to figure out which number that is.

I have tried several things, but none have worked. Is there another command I can add on to it or is there a better way to search for the missing index number?

Comment: Is always there a space between `"index":` and `number`?

Comment: Is your input actually JSON? If so, could you post a more well-formed JSON document?

Comment: The `cat` was unnecessary there: simple `grep index <file` or `grep index file` would be fine.

Comment: Obviously you need a loop that counts up the index and compares that to the index found in the file's line. If there is a mismatch, you found the missing index. As the answers indicate, there are many ways to do it. Pick your favorite language. Maybe show what you tried; so any answer will fit your needs batter as they do now.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672996/how-can-i-see-if-a-consecutive-number-name-file-is-missing-some-file/673092#673092 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236164/how-to-find-missing-files-with-sequential-names and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219031/how-to-print-the-name-of-missing-files-in-a-folder

Comment: Did this migrate over from Code Golf SE? It’s a perfect question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a; for lines() {@a.push: $/.Int if .match(/<?after \"index\"\: \s > \d+ /) };  \
            put ((1..10) (-) @a.Set).keys.sort;'  index.txt

#OR

~$ raku -e 'my @a; for lines() {@a.push: $0.Int if .match(/<?after \"index\"\: \s > (\d+) /) };  \
            put ((1..10) (-) @a.Set).keys.sort;'  index.txt
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. It was released in 2015 as Perl_6, and renamed Raku in 2019. Consequently, you'll find many "Perl-isms" in Raku.

One interesting feature of Raku is Set semantics. Unicode as well as ASCII operators are available. In the code above, ASCII `(-)` stands for **Set difference (non-symmetric)**. You can also use Unicode:

```
∖
SET MINUS
Unicode: U+2216, UTF-8: E2 88 96
```

Sample Input (note max value is 100):

```
"index": 1
"index": 2
"index": 3
"index": 5
"index": 100
```

Sample Output (both code examples):

```
4 6 7 8 9 10
```

Caveat:  It can be easy to confuse symmetric and non-symmetric Set operations. For example, with the code above if you reverse the order of sets and try the ASCII `(^)` or Unicode `⊖` **symmetric Set difference** operator instead, you'll see a big difference (using `1..99` as the test range):

```
~$ cat index.txt | perl6 -e 'my @a = do for lines() {$/.Int if .match(/<?after \"index\"\: \s > \d+ /) }; put (@a.Set (-) (1..99)).keys.sort;'
100
~$ cat index.txt | perl6 -e 'my @a = do for lines() {$/.Int if .match(/<?after \"index\"\: \s > \d+ /) }; put (@a.Set (^) (1..99)).keys.sort;'
4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/setbagmix
https://raku.org

Answer (score 6):

You can use `diff` command to get the differences between your file and the sequence of number from N to M. The `awk` command is used to parse the text and get only the numbers:

```bash
diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines  <(awk '{print $2}' file.txt) <(seq 1 10001) | awk '{print $2}'
```

The code above compare the numbers of your file with the sequence from `1` to `10001`.

For a more *functional* way to implement this you can detect the last number of your file (10001) and assign it to a variable:

```bash
max=$(tail -1 file.txt | awk '{print $2}')
diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines  <(awk '{print $2}' file.txt) <(seq 1 $max) | awk '{print $2}'
```

For example, having this:

**file.txt**:

```
"index": 1
"index": 5
"index": 8
"index": 9
"index": 10
"index": 12
"index": 13
"index": 15
```

```bash
max=$(tail -1 file.txt | awk '{print $2}')
diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines  <(awk '{print $2}' file.txt) <(seq 1 $max) | awk '{print $2}'
```

**Output:**

```
2
3
4
6
7
11
14
```

By the way, if you want to print the missing values in this format: `"index": the_missing_number` you could change the last `awk print` statement like this:

```bash
diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines  <(awk '{print $2}' file.txt) <(seq 1 $max) | awk '{print "\"index\": "$2}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Two important assumptions about the file that contains the index labels and integers, from your example:

```
"index": 1
"index": 2
"index": 3
...
"index": 10001
```

The assumptions are:

1. When read from the first line to the last, the index integers are in ascending order.
2. One or more spaces or tabs separate the `"index":` label from the index integer.

As long as both are true, this small loop in `bash` can output missing numbers (but read my caveat after the code).  The file with the index labels and integers is named `indexes.txt`:

```
cur_idx=0
last_idx=0
while read label cur_idx; do
  (( last_idx != ( cur_idx - 1 ))) && echo $(( cur_idx - 1 ))
  last_idx=${cur_idx}
done < indexes.txt
```

The loop remembers the last index seen, and after it reads a new index line, it compares the current (new) index [minus 1] with the last index.  When they're not equal, an index was skipped and it prints the skipped index.

### Caveat:

If there are two or more consecutive missing indexes, this loop will only print out the first missing one.  It won't print all of them.
I.e., if you have:

```
"index": 21
"index": 24
```

(missing `22` and `23`), the loop will only print `22`.  However, that will let you look at the `indexes.txt` file after `21` and see how many numbers were skipped.  I get the impression from your question that there are only one or two missing indexes, so this shouldn't hinder you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a simple grep/awk statement.  The first line matching index  that does not have the same number as the awk line number (NR) then print the line number and exit.

```bash
grep index file | awk -F: '{ if (NR != $2 ) {print "missing " NR; exit;} }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the input is a JSON file consisting of a top-level array of object, each with some `index` key, like so:

```json
[
  {
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "index": 3
  },
  {
    "index": 4
  },
  {
    "index": 6
  },
  {
    "index": 7
  },
  {
    "index": 10
  }
]
```

We may then use the JSON processor `jq` to pick out the `index` values of the first and last element of the array, create a set of numbers that span that range (apart from the actual first and last values), and then output the ones of those that do not correspond to an existing `index` value:

```bash
$ jq '[.[].index] as $i | ($i|range(first+1;last)) | select( IN($i[]) | not )' file
5
8
9
```

If the input is *unordered*, you will want to change `range(first+1;last)` to `range(min+1;max)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this purely in `awk`:

```
awk '$1=="\"index\":"{if (last && $2!=(last+1)) {printf "Missing index: %d\n",last+1;}; last=$2}' input.txt
```

This will only process files whose first "word" is `"index":`. The second "word" of that line (`$2`) will be treated as the ID.

- The ID value of the previous index line is stored in a variable `last`. The variable is empty at the beginning.
- If there was already a "previous" index line (`last` evaluates to non-empty), and the current index value is different from the last index plus one, the missing value is printed as "Missing index".
- In any case, the `last` value is updated to the index value of the current line.
- If, as you write, there will only be *one single* missing index value in the entire file, you can skip processing the remaining file by adding an `exit` command after the `printf()` call.

This allows for the indices starting at a value other than 1 (which however must still be positive), but assumes that there can only be *single missing values*. If more than one consecutive indices can be missing, the following adaptation will print ranges of missing indices:

```
awk '$1=="\"index\":"{if (last && $2!=(last+1)) {for (t=last+1;t<$2;t++) printf "Missing index: %d\n",t}; last=$2}' input.txt
```

This is accomplished by a `for` loop iterating from `last+1` (the first missing index) to one less than the current line index.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner using just `jot` and `diff`, without any unnecessary parsing or `awk` steps:

```
$ diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines <(jot -w '"index": %d' 10001) file
```

This method simply generates a known-good output sample, and compares `file` to the known-good sample.

Test:

```
$ jot -w '"index": %d' 6665 > testfile
$ jot -w '"index": %d' - 6667 10001 >> testfile
$ diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines <(jot -w '"index": %d' 10001) testfile
"index": 6666
```

Answer (score 0):

Will detect any gaps and single absences in consecutive, ascending numbering.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^"index":$/ {while(++i<$2)print $1, i}' file
```

Answer (score -3):

A loop?
Something like

```
for i in {1..10001}
do
  if ! grep "\"index\": $i" then
      echo Missing index $i
  fi
done
```

Comment: Grepping the file 10000 times?

Comment: Or temporary file with just indexes. And why not? There was no requirements for efficiency, only for ease of implementation. For efficiency - use perl or awk.

Comment: Hm ... I could not find any reference that the OP required ease of implementation, though.